# Encrypted Samba 4 share

Tags: linux, encryption, samba

I'm on Fedora 31 and I've set up a password protected Samba share, however as I'm on an untrusted network I would like to encrypt the traffic to protect myself from monitoring, and from what I can tell Samba does not enforce this.

I will have Windows 10, MacOS, and Linux clients.

Setting the encrypt = required flag only results in `Unknown parameter encountered` from `testparm -s`. Is there some other way to enable this?

**smb.conf:**

```
[global]
        workgroup = SIMERNES
        security = user

        passdb backend = tdbsam

        printing = cups
        printcap name = cups
        load printers = yes
        cups options = raw
        encrypt = required

[shared]
        comment = Shared Folder
        path = /home/smbuser/sambashare
        valid users = smbuser
        public = yes
        writable = yes
        write list = samba
        create mask = 0777
        directory mask = 0777
        printable = no
```

`smbd -V` returns `4.11.4`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option is actually called `smb encrypt =`.